# phonegap version 3.3.0 does not work in iphone 4

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

i developed app with phonegap.it generate .ipa file with version 3.3.0.
   but when i installed that app in my  iphone 4(IOS 7.1.1) it installed but  it does not work
   it does not load

Comment: Device UDID may be missed out !

Comment: @jeekonline https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action in here i looked UDID  it is same with my phone...but in organizer in myphone there is no provisioning profiles ...is this problem ?   http://i.hizliresim.com/aqkkNR.png

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap Build v 3.3.0 works fine with iOS7. I've been using it (though I'm now mostly using 3.4 and will be using 3.5).

If your app installs but does not load it is likely a problem with your code.

You cannot install an app to an iOS device without having a development signing key in PhoneGap Build. See the PhoneGap Build docs for how to get one - the docs are pretty good. If you have any problems with it google "iOS certificates and provisioning profiles explained". There are a few tutorials out there.